# Having trouble fixing a query, output generates unwanted result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing the query listed below. I noticed for the output I am getting duplicated results. I suspect the table included both primary market and secondary market. Here primary market looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO trade
  (trade_id, stock_id, transaction_time, shares, price_total,buyer_id, seller_id) 
VALUES
  (trade_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 7, SYSDATE-190, 200000, 82000000, 25, 6);
```

secondary market looks like this:

```
    INSERT INTO trade
      (trade_id,stock_ex_id,stock_id, transaction_time, shares, price_total, buyer_id, seller_id, buy_broker_id, sell_broker_id) 
VALUES
      (trade_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 3, 1, SYSDATE-190, 1000, 619500, 19, 20, 12, 5);
```

[Here is the ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH4ga.jpg)

Notice the secondary market has 3 more values than the primary. I joined trade table with stock_exchange table on t.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id and it should filter out primary market trades but somehow they still show up in my table and I am not sure how to fix this.

Here is my output:

```
trade_id  stock symbol  stock exchange name    se symbol   shares    price total   currency
  11           GOOG      British Airways        NYSE       84000      1046892         $
  11           NYT       Toyota Motors          NYSE       84000      1046892         $
  11           TM        BNP Paribas            NYSE       84000      1046892         $
  11           IBM       Google                 NYSE       84000      1046892         $
  18           BA        The New York Times     LSE        72000      14711256        £
  28           GOOG      British Airways        NYSE       50300      4099128.08      $
  28           NYT       Toyota Motors          NYSE       50300      4099128.08      $
  28           TM        BNP Paribas            NYSE       50300      4099128.08      $
  28           IBM       Google                 NYSE       50300      4099128.08      $
```

Question:

Write a query which displays all trades where more than 50000 shares were traded on the secondary markets.
Please include the trade id, stock symbol, name of the company being traded, stock exchange symbol, number of shares traded,
price total and currency symbol. Sort the result by trade id.

```
SELECT
   t.trade_id,
   sl.stock_symbol,
   co.name,
   se.symbol,
   t.shares,
   t.price_total,
   cu.symbol
FROM trade t
    JOIN stock_exchange se
        ON t.stock_ex_id = se.stock_ex_id
    JOIN stock_listing sl
        ON se.stock_ex_id = sl.stock_ex_id
    JOIN company co
        ON co.company_id = sl.stock_id
    JOIN currency cu 
        on cu.currency_id = se.currency_id
WHERE t.shares > 50000
ORDER BY t.trade_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably not caused by primary and secondary shares, there are too many values repeated for that. (You've only inserted two records and one of them has a null in the column you join so it doesn't participate in the join)

Try to look at the data as "N columns that repeat themselves" matched against "N columns that are unique"

The unique columns are symbol and company name. Symbol comes from sl, co Name is joined to sl - the join between these two tables is ok and 1:1.

The other columns that have repeated data come from t, cu and se and they are probably joined ok too within themselves.

So we look at how the sl+co columns are connected to the t+cu+se, which is on a join from se to sl.

The problem seems then to be coming from this join between se and sl; multiple different se rows are matching against one sl row which causes the sl row to repeat (causing all the other data it is connected to to repeat

Often one of the simpler ways to solve these problems is to make it `SELECT *` and comment out all your tables except two, trade and sl, run the query, check for no repeated rows, add another table, run again, if there are repeated rows fix the join condition so there aren't, add another table...

Break it down. Look at joins in isolation/one by one

Comment: Followed this advice and debugged table by table and the problem is not the primary/secondary market it is from current_shareholder_shares table when I join with trade. Also solved other problems relating to this. Much thanks!